# Notifications from firebase when app is in foreground not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to setup a system where an Android mobile phone receives notification from a server: for this task we have chosen Firebase.
While the application is in background everything works fine: after I push a message from the firebase console a notification appears on the system tray and, after the message is clicked by the user, an `Intent` with extra data is sent to the `Activity`.

My problem is uniquely when the application is already in foreground. The [firebase notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience#receive_and_handle_notifications) is pretty clear: **if the application is in foreground, no matter which type of message is sent by the server, `OnMessageReceived` is never called**... so why it fails with my simple app? Some notes to help you solve this issue:

- we're working with Android Studio 2.1.2;
- "it.bagozi.ada.tutorial.firebase" contains both classes (as you might deduce from the pacakge declaration);

Below you can find all the source code used:

**Main Activity**

```
package it.bagozi.ada.tutorial.firebase;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView notification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.notification = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.notification_setter);

        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        Log.e(TAG, "Intent from Activity caller: " + i);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
                Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**FirebaseNotificationService**

```
package it.bagozi.ada.tutorial.firebase;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = FirebaseNotificationService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }


}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.bagozi.ada.tutorial.firebase">

    <service android:name=".FirebaseNotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the service declaration in your manifest a child of the "application" tag!

Comment: it's incredible how another pair of eyes can solve an issue in so little time! Just tried and work flawlessly!